# How can I add dynamically where clauses in spring boot? Please tell me your approach

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot and I use an interface that extends from CrudRepository, but for some of the queries I need more control. Before with spring I used to do something like this:

```
String queryStr = "SELECT s.clave, Descripcion, CAST(Cantidad1 AS SIGNED) cantidad,"
                    + " (SELECT SUM(NrCompInt) FROM TransacSQL.Items i WHERE transacNr IN(SELECT DISTINCT ObserIng FROM ComunSql.Trazabi t WHERE t.nrTransacSalida = 0 AND t.articulo = ea.Clave) AND i.Articulo = ea.Clave) valorizacion"
                    + " FROM ComunSql.ExiArt ea" + " INNER JOIN ComunSql.Stock s ON ea.Clave = s.Clave"
                    + " WHERE ea.Cantidad1 > 0";

            if (!idArticulo.isEmpty())
                queryStr += " AND s.Clave = :idArticulo";

            if (idExistencia != -1)
                queryStr += " AND ea.NrExist = :idExistencia";

            Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryStr);
```

Comment: There is a tool called `query-dsl` that works good in those kind of tasks. There are good online guides on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to read the guides.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create your desired queries , you can use criteria based condition and adding them to the query then execute them with aid of repositories or data access operation level of you application. beside that you can create your own desired query by creating the string and native queries(same as what you trying to do), please note that this approach isn't called DSL query briefly saying the DSL queries are query syntax thats created for Apache Lucene or any Lucene based data bases like Elasticsearch.

For the case in hand consider that we passed controller implementing and service interface and we are in service implementing,  we do create a buffered string that satisfy the related query syntax(TSQL, DSL etc) and the logic that i want to query executed then i pass it to repository class that extend to spring boot data that i used in my project .

Consider below example which our spring data based on Elasticsearch

```html
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> SearchCore(SequenceSearchDTO entity, Pageable pageable) {

        String query="";
        Double z=0.00;
        Long x=z.longValue();
        if(entity.getParentKnowledgeGroupId() != null && !entity.getParentKnowledgeGroupId().isEmpty() && !entity.getParentKnowledgeGroupId().equals("")){
            query= "[{\"query_string\": { \"query\" : \""+entity.getParentKnowledgeGroupId()+"\", \"fields\" : [ \"parentKnowledgeGroupId\" ] }}," ;
        }
        if(entity.getKnowledgeGroupId() != null && !entity.getKnowledgeGroupId().isEmpty() && !entity.getKnowledgeGroupId().equals("")){
            query=query+ "{\"query_string\" : { \"query\" : \""+entity.getKnowledgeGroupId()+"\", \"fields\" : [ \"knowledgeGroupId\" ]}},";
        }
        if(entity.getTerm() != null && !entity.getTerm().isEmpty() && !entity.getTerm().equals("")){
            query=query+ "{\"query_string\" : { \"query\" : \""+entity.getTerm()+"\", \"fields\" : [ \"content\" ]}},";
        }
        if(entity.getPrice() != null && ! entity.getPrice().equals("")){
            query=query+"{\"range\" : {\"price\" : {\"from\" :"+x+" , \"to\" : "+entity.getPrice()+", \"include_lower\" : true, \"include_upper\" : true } } },";
        }

        if(entity.getCourseType() != null && ! entity.getCourseType().equals("")){
            query=query+ "{\"query_string\" : { \"query\" : \""+entity.getCourseType()+"\", \"fields\" : [ \"courseType\" ]}},";
        }
        if(entity.getScore() != null && ! entity.getScore().equals("")){
            System.out.println("+++++");
            System.out.println(entity.getScore());
            query=query+"{\"range\" : {\"scoree\" : {\"from\" : "+0+", \"to\" : "+entity.getScore()+", \"include_lower\" : true, \"include_upper\" : false } } },";
        }
        if(entity.getBeginDate() != null && ! entity.getBeginDate().equals("")){

            if(entity.getEndDate() != null && ! entity.getEndDate().equals("")) {
                query = query + "{\"range\" : {\"LogicalDate\" : {\"from\" : " + entity.getBeginDate().getTime() / 1000 + ", \"to\" : " + entity.getEndDate().getTime() / 1000 + ", \"include_lower\" : true, \"include_upper\" : true } } },";
            }
            else{
                query=query+ "{\"range\" : {\"LogicalDate\" : {\"from\" : "+entity.getBeginDate().getTime()/1000+", \"to\" : "+new Date().getTime()/1000+", \"include_lower\" : true, \"include_upper\" : true } } },";
            }
        }
        if(entity.getDuration() != null && ! entity.getDuration().equals("")){
            query=query+"{\"range\" : {\"studyTime\" : {\"from\" :"+x+" , \"to\" : "+entity.getDuration()+", \"include_lower\" : true, \"include_upper\" : true } } },";
        }
        if(entity.getFree() != null){
            query=query+ "{\"query_string\" : { \"query\" : \""+entity.getFree()+"\", \"fields\" : [ \"free\" ]}}]";
        }

        Page<ElasticModelSequence> flag=sequenceRepository.stringQuery(query, pageable);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(flag);
    }
```

Finally passing it to the related repository

```html
@Repository
public interface SequenceRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ElasticModelSequence, String> {

    @Query("{\"bool\":"+
            "{\"must\" :"+
            "?0"+
            "}"+
            "}")
    Page<ElasticModelSequence> stringQuery(@Param("flag") String flag, Pageable pageable);

}
```